# Is there any open source tool that automatically 'detects' email threading like Gmail?

Tags: email, open-source, gmail, email-parsing, email-threading

For instance, if the original message (message 1) is...

> Hey Jon,
>   Want to go get some pizza?
>   -Bill

And the reply (message 2) is...

> Bill,
>   Sorry, I can't make lunch today.
>   Jonathon Parks, CTO Acme Systems
>
> On Wed, Feb 24, 2010 at 4:43 PM, Bill Waters  wrote:
>
> > Hey John,
>   > Want to go get some pizza?
>   > -Bill

In Gmail, the system (a) detects that message 2 is a reply to message 1 and turns this into a 'thread' of sorts and (b) detects *where* the replied portion of the message actually is and hides it from the user. (In this case the hidden portion would start at "On Wed, Feb..." and continue to the end of the message.)

Obviously, in this simple example it would be easy to detect the "On <Date>, <Name> wrote:" or the ">" character prefixes. But many email systems have many different style of marking replies (not to mention HTML emails). I get the feeling that you would have to have some damn smart string parsing algorithms to get anywhere near how good GMail's is.

Does this technology already exist in an open source project somewhere? Either in some library devoted to this exclusively or perhaps in some open source email client that does similar message threading?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible solutions

Whoops, upon more searching I think I may have found what I was looking for right here in these threads:

stackoverflow.com/questions/262234/algorithm-for-organizing-emails-into-threads
stackoverflow.com/questions/1966937/email-threading

...reference a discussion about "In-Reply-To" headers http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-Settings-en/browse_thread/thread/9b6ad523513e1858 as well as an algorithm for doing approximately what I'm talking about http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html and a ruby implementation of that algorithm http://github.com/fdietz/jwz_threading.

Comment: Answering your own question is allowed & encouraged. Feel free to do so. :)

Comment: have you ran across an objective-c implementation of Jamie's [algorithm](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html)?

Comment: just to answer my own comment.. i found a C implementation of the algorithm [here](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/nsanch/balsa-1.2.pre2/src/balsa-index-threading.c) as part of the open source [Balsa](http://balsa.gnome.org/download.html) email client (runs only on linux.. but that's no [problem](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/05/09/how-to-install-linux-applications-in-os-x-a-complete-walkthrough/) for mac users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good article written by Zawinski here:

http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gmail works by **subject title**. I can't check it at the moment, but a quick change to the title might break the threading.

The following is difficult to predict, as you mention:

```
On Wed, Feb 24, 2010 at 4:43 PM, Bill Waters wrote:
```

but grabbing the email title `Pizza tomorrow` and assuming a prefix of `Re: Pizza tomorrow` is considerably more predictable. You could also assume the cases of `FW:` and `RE:` (in caps).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to solve problems where the correspondent doesn't set In-Reply-To: or References: header fields?

Otherwise, you might use mutt and configure it to not show quotes by default.

(Should be done by any other mail-tool on earth too. (Well, i never got a tree-thread-view in Outlook.)

[edited below in reaction to comment]

If you try to build your own software, then this question obviously is suited well. But then, I can only give you my 2c on this. If you cannot rely on the explicit headers, than the only thing to do is take a bunch of mails, learn the most common phrases used to indicate quotes. (Luckily there are some conventions, and date formats and names/emails are not completely arbitrary.)

If you do this for analysis of communication threads, you probably want to indicate the likelyness of the relation. If you only do it for convenience of the user... well,... my personal opinion? Don't sweat about people not able to use a decent mailtool.

Comment: I'm developing a software tool which (among other things) is going to need to take a bunch of raw email messages and using whatever information possible build a 'tree' or 'thread' structure out of the messages.

I'm only just learning about In-Reply-To: and References: headers in RFC822 emails. It looks like I'll be using that data, but they might be missing in some cases so I'm looking perhaps for some heuristic-driven approach to determining "what is a response to what".

Answer (score 0):

What kind of [Mail Delivery Agent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_Delivery_Agent) are you using?

Are you developing your own? In that case, are you planning to implement IMAP protocol?

If you're using Cyrus (or any other product that handles IMAP) with [SORT and THREAD extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256), then it's already built in.

In both cases, you should take a look at [RFC 5256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256).

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look at sup http://freshmeat.net/articles/sup-gmail-meets-the-console as it does almost what you want